# Multiple Hadoop clusters in one Google Cloud project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-hadoop

Is it possible to deploy several Hadoop clusters in one Google Cloud project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [bdutil](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/downloads) you can deploy arbitrarily many different Hadoop clusters in a single Google project, as long as you've obtained sufficient [Google Compute Engine quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/resource-quotas) to do so. The [instructions here](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/setting-up-a-hadoop-cluster#configuringacluster) describe the usage of bdutil, but in short, cluster names in bdutil are simply distinguished by the `PREFIX` variable or `--prefix` flag when using bdutil. It's up to you to keep track of the zone and numbers of workers in each bdutil cluster.

For easily keeping track of multiple clusters, it's highly recommended to use bdutil's `generate_config` command. For example, suppose you want 3 clusters: `test`, `staging` and `prod`. And perhaps they're different sizes and in different zones. You'll want to run something like:

```
./bdutil --prefix my-test-cluster -n 2 -z us-central1-f -b test-bucket  \
    generate_config test-cluster_env.sh

./bdutil --prefix my-staging-cluster -n 5 -z us-central1-b -b staging-bucket  \
    generate_config staging-cluster_env.sh

./bdutil --prefix my-prod-cluster -n 10 -z us-central1-f -b prod-bucket  \
    generate_config prod-cluster_env.sh
```

Once you've done that, the files `test-cluster_env.sh`, `staging-cluster_env.sh` and `prod-cluster_env.sh` can be used to refer to your three different clusters from now on. For example, suppose you want to delete your test cluster:

```
./bdutil -e test-cluster_env.sh delete
```

Or just deploy your prod cluster:

```
./bdutil -e prod-cluster_env.sh deploy
```

Or to SSH into the master of your staging cluster:

```
./bdutil -e staging-cluster_env.sh shell
```

When you do it this way, you can store your *_cluster_env.sh files in source control, and they'll be backwards compatible whenever you upgrade bdutil with new Google releases.

If you need to customize bdutil more extensively, you may want to consider obtaining bdutil from GitHub directly using:

```
git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bdutil.git
```

So that you can use git to update to fresh versions of bdutil periodically while letting git resolve any merge conflicts with any customizations.